# Can Flyway be used to migrate tables between different databases without migration file?

Tags: database, jdbc, flyway, data-migration

There are many questions like this on Stack Overflow, but it seems to me that they already have the migration scripts in place. For example, `insert` and `update` statements are available, as such, Flyway can just use those scripts to create the tables in the target database and its data.

However, my question is that, what if we don't have those scripts? For example, tables are being created manually or with some other tools and the data are being inserted over the years with the bound application, now we want to switch to a different SQL database. Can Flyway be used as a tool to transfer all the tables and databases only with providing connections?

If the answer is no, how this sort of migration can be done and what are the best practices.

I did a search and went through Flyway documentation but they are all vague and doesn't give you a clear example of that. Some of these tools I found are used for Salesforce but I need a tool/library that possibly can be used in Java using JDBC connection, or other languages such as Python etc, as our databases - for security reasons - cannot be accessed directly and are cloud based.

For your information, we are using a range of databases PostgreSQL, Aurora MySQL, SQL Server.

Comment: Flyway is not a data migration tool, it is a schema migration tool. It cannot do what you want. And requests for tool suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ok what if I reword it to 'how' we can do it rather than requesting for a tool suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

No, Flyway can't do this sort of thing.

Flyway is a deployment tool. While it certainly can include data movement, as with the deployment of database objects, the scripts supporting data movement have to be completely idempotent or completely isolated in their deployment. Neither of these is lending itself to what you're talking about.

What you're talking about is something like [Redgate SQL Compare](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) along with SQL Data Compare. These two would allow you to compare two databases, identify the differences, then generate the necessary scripts. I'm aware of no open source tools that do all that, especially that do all that across multiple data platforms. And that tool only supports SQL Server (there is a second one for Oracle, but no others).

The thing is, if you're allowing deployments to occur using manual processes or 3rd party mechanisms, without going through source control as centralized management of your code, you can't use Flyway anyway. Flyway requires a consistent and stable process wherein it is the thing running deployments. Allowing, or even encouraging, drift through out-of-band deployments will break your Flyway deployments.

DISCLOSURE: I work for Redgate, but we're not the solution you're looking for.